# Routing Razor Pages to /example.com/en/ format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, .net-core, razor-pages

I have three languages on my website. I'm trying to get my razor pages to route to culture/localization like so:

```
https://localhost:44396/en/
https://localhost:44396/ru/
```

I have hundreds of lines of code commented out at this point using methods I've been googling for the past two days and nothing seems to do the job.
The website is mostly static so right now beyond the culture there is nothing else that needs routing.

Comment: A lot of interesting guidance in the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: @Nkosi I've looked over the official docs and attempted to implement a few methods several times to no avail.

Comment: Here are two other ones that should be helpful https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/310/routing-in-razor-pages and https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Comment: @Nkosi As I mentioned I used google and stumbled upon those resources as well and attempted to implement them without success.

Comment: @AgonEous did you come up with a good solution?

Comment: @PussInBoots My solution was to forego using razor pages and opt for pure MVC.

Comment: Okay, too bad it didn't work with razor pages. Ms should provide more real life samples in their docs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do it that doesn't require you to put a middleware attribute on all of your pages. This works globally.

In the `ConfigureServices` method of Startup.cs, add the following:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
     options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model => {
         foreach (var selector in model.Selectors) {
             selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{lang=en}", selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template);
         }
     });
 });

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
    var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
    var supportedCultures = new CultureInfo[] {
        defaultCulture,
        new CultureInfo("fr")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture);
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() {
        RouteDataStringKey = "lang",
        UIRouteDataStringKey = "lang",
        Options = options
    });
});
```

This sets up the global route, your supported cultures, and sets the primary culture provider to come from the route. (This still leaves the other providers intact, so failing the Route values, it can still set the culture based on the Query String, Cookies, or Language Header.)

Now, in your `Configure` method (still in Startup.cs), add the following:

```
var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(app) {
    DefaultHandler = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MvcRouteHandler>(),
};
routeBuilder.Routes.Insert(0, AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(app.ApplicationServices));
var router = routeBuilder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    var routeContext = new RouteContext(context);
    await router.RouteAsync(routeContext);

    context.Features[typeof(IRoutingFeature)] = new RoutingFeature() {
        RouteData = routeContext.RouteData
    };

    await next();
});

var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
app.UseMvc();
```

There's some trickery here. Firstly, we have to call `app.UseRequestLocalization` before we call `app.UseMvc`, or else our program will run before we've changed the current culture. But the problem is, `app.UseMvc()` is the one that sets up RouteData. So, until you call it, the routing values are all blank. Ergo, when the `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` goes to try and observe what {lang} is, it'll come back empty, and thus always default you to **en**. Catch 22.

So, we just go manually populate the RouteData ourselves in our own custom middleware. That way, the RouteDataRequestCultureProvider can see it, and all will work well.

(I admit this is not the most efficient, as you're just duplicating the routing work that `app.UseMvc()` will itself also do, but I'll take that unnoticeable delay to ensure all my pages are localized.)

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you what I do which works. The only difference is that I use the 5 characters language code but I guess it is not something difficult to change.

Make sure that you have the following nuget library installed

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing
```

In the ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs we type the following code under the servcies.AddMvc();

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
        options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
        {
            foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
            {
                var attributeRouteModel = selector.AttributeRouteModel;
                attributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{lang=el-GR}", attributeRouteModel.Template);
            }
        });
    });

IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
    new CultureInfo("el-GR"),
};

var MyOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
MyOptions.RequestCultureProviders = new[]
{
     new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { RouteDataStringKey = "lang", Options = MyOptions }        // requires nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing
};

services.AddSingleton(MyOptions);
```

We add the following class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
public class LocalizationPipeline
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, RequestLocalizationOptions options)
    {
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
    }
}
```

Now you have to add the following line over your PageModel class:

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(LocalizationPipeline))]
public class ContactModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: In short I get this:    InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RequestLocalizationOptions' has been registered.

          Slightly longer comment is: I want to avoid touching any of the behind code for all individual pages so this answer is more of a workaround even if it were to work.