# Routed localization in ASP.NET Core 3.0 Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I would like to use routed localization in my ASP.NET Core 3.0 Razor Pages application.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52976625/107718 seems to have a solution for 2.2 but is there any better way of doing this in 3.0 now that it have routing/endpoints reworked?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5061604/Developing-Multicultural-ASP-NET-Core-3-2-1-Projec) can help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 introduces a new feature of Endpoint Routing by which we can get the culture from the route data before it goes into MVC. This allows us to localize  content according to current route without too much effort.

#### How-to

Firstly, make sure the Localization Service is registered & you've configured supported culture as below:

```
services.AddLocalization(opts =>  opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources" );
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]{
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("de"),
        new CultureInfo("it"),
        // ... others
    };
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
});
```

And then add an `UseRequestLocalization` Middleware and configure a route for culture such that it can get the culture info correctly:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseRequestLocalization();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "culture-route", pattern:"{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute( name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Note the above **orders** are important.

#### Demo:

[image]

---

**[Edit]**

Sorry, I didn't notice that you asked for the Razor Page. To work with Razor Page WebApp, create a custom `IPageRouteModelConvention` to map the route:

```
public class CustomCultureRouteRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        List<SelectorModel> selectorModels = new List<SelectorModel>();
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
            selectorModels.Add(new SelectorModel(){
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = "/{culture}" + "/" + template
                }
            });
        }
        foreach(var m in selectorModels){
            model.Selectors.Add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

And add this page conventions :

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(opts =>
{
    opts.Conventions.Add(new CustomCultureRouteRouteModelConvention());
});
services.AddLocalization(opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]{
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("de"),
        new CultureInfo("it"),
        new CultureInfo("zh"),
    };
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
});
```

The middlewares :

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseRequestLocalization();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "culture-route", pattern:"{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    //endpoints.MapControllerRoute( name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: This would work for MVC but how do I do it for Razor pages? Inside `UseEndpoints` I have to use `MapRazorPages` and that doesn't have any options.

Comment: @Regent Sorry, I didn't notice that you was asking for Razor Pages. Please see my updated answer for how to do that.

Comment: @itminus when I try this code, it works for any strings like `/abc/Privacy`. Now it shouldn't work for strings like that only for `/{validCulture}/Privacy`. How can you check if the culture exists?