# Route Data in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is this from MVC supported in razor pages?

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "prefix",
                    pattern: "{prefix}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

I need a prefix in front of page url:

```
/prefix/Index

/prefix/Privacy
```

I can access the route data, just don't know how to map it to razor page

Answer (score 2):

To implement it in razor pages, first create a class that inherits from `IPageRouteModelConvention`

```
public class CustomRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        List<SelectorModel> selectorModels = new List<SelectorModel>();
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
            selectorModels.Add(new SelectorModel()
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = "/prefix" + "/" + template
                }
            });
        }
        foreach (var m in selectorModels)
        {
            model.Selectors.Add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in startup.cs `ConfigureServices` method, add this code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(opts =>
        {
            opts.Conventions.Add(new CustomRouteModelConvention());
        });
     }
```

This is refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721157/routed-localization-in-asp-net-core-3-0-razor-pages).

**Update:**

To make 'prefix' dynamically, you can change 'prefix' to `{0}` to replace any string you input.

```
public class CustomRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        List<SelectorModel> selectorModels = new List<SelectorModel>();
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
            selectorModels.Add(new SelectorModel()
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = "/{0}" + "/" + template
                }
            });
        }
        foreach (var m in selectorModels)
        {
            model.Selectors.Add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: OK, this sort of works, Template = "/{prefix}" + "/" + template, how do i now generate the links to follow the added prefix? note that prefix is dynamic and not hard coded

Comment: In MVC once you applied something like this: https://localhost:44306/Test/Index - all the links will follow the Test prefix, when you hover over Privacy it will go to https://localhost:44306/Test/Privacy

Comment: @Seeker I have updated my post based on your requirement,  you can try it.

Comment: "prefix" is dynamic, it could be test1/privacy, test2/privacy, test3/privacy then i use the route value to display data

Comment: @Seeker I have updated my post , hope it can solve your issue.